# Python Pandas Dataframes - Merge smaller df with much larger df and overwrite data in larger df from smaller based on two same columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've seen a lot of other posts on this but none really seemed to be asking the same question that I could find. So I have two dataframes, an example would be something like this:

df1: (*Edit* This df is about 50 rows and 6 columns)

```
Part Number   Operation   Part Description   Operation Description
1111          1.0.0       Stator             Withdraw
1111          1.0.1       Labyrinth          Issue Material
1222          1.0.0       Fuel Slinger       Deburr
1222          1.0.1       Assembly           Final Inspection
```

df2: (*Edit* This df is much larger, almost 10k rows and 50 columns)

```
Part Number   Operation   Part Description   Operation Description   Project   Lead     Status
1111          1.0.0       Seal Assembly      Clean Parts             Blue      James    Green
1111          1.0.1       Stator             Machine Vane Tips       Blue      Jeff     Yellow
1222          1.0.0       Fuel Slinger       Store                   Green     Steve    Red
1222          1.0.1       Blade              Soak                    Purple    Jessica  Yellow
1233          1.0.0       ECU                Design                  Orange    Adam     Green
1233          1.0.1       Seal Assembly      Clean Parts             Phoenix   Ashley   Green
1234          1.0.0       Stator             Machine Vane Tips       Blue      Colin    Red
1234          1.0.1       STG SUB            Identify                Purple    Amanda   Green
```

My ideal output would be to overwrite 'Part Description' and 'Operation Description' in df2 with the data from df1, so it would look like this:

df3:

```
Part Number   Operation   Part Description   Operation Description   Project   Lead     Status
1111          1.0.0       Stator             Withdraw                Blue      James    Green
1111          1.0.1       Labyrinth          Issue Material          Blue      Jeff     Yellow
1222          1.0.0       Fuel Slinger       Deburr                  Green     Steve    Red
1222          1.0.1       Assembly           Final Inspection        Purple    Jessica  Yellow
1233          1.0.0       ECU                Design                  Orange    Adam     Green
1233          1.0.1       Seal Assembly      Clean Parts             Phoenix   Ashley   Green
1234          1.0.0       Stator             Machine Vane Tips       Blue      Colin    Red
1234          1.0.1       STG SUB            Identify                Purple    Amanda   Green
```

I've been mainly trying different joins and combinations with dataframe.join() and pandas.merge(), something like this for dataframe.join():

```
def mergeRawBopDataAndPNS():
    pnsdf = readPNSfromExcel()
    updateData = queryPartNum()
    joinHeaders = ['Part Number', 'Operation']
    pnsdf = pnsdf.set_index(joinHeaders).join(updateData.set_index(joinHeaders))
    return pnsdf
```

Or something with pandas.merge() like this:

```
def mergeRawBopDataAndPNS():
    pnsdf = readPNSfromExcel()
    updateData = queryPartNum()
    joinHeaders = ['Part Number', 'Operation']
    outdf = pd.merge(pnsdf, updateData, how='left', on=joinHeaders)
    return outdf
```

But no matter what I've done I can't get my ideal output. I've got some knowledge gaps here in how to merge these two dataframes.

Comment: can you check if [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) does what you want?

Comment: It's close @mozway, but is there any way to get dataframe.update() to update based on conditions? Like if part number and operation in df1 is the same as df2, then update?

Comment: well, you need to (temporarily) set as index what you want to merge on ;)

Comment: Hm, this is giving me ideas. It's definitely better than the attempts I have been making. I'll look into this more, I appreciate it @mozway

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes do something similar using concat. Here is an example function

```
def update_shared_columns(df1, df2):
    merge_keys = [k for k in df2 if k in df1]
    df3 = pd.concat([df1[merge_keys], df2[merge_keys]])
    df3 = df3[~df3.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
    return pd.concat([df3[merge_keys], df1[[k for k in df1 if k not in merge_keys]]], axis=1).sort_index()
```

it works in 3 steps

1. creates a dataframe object with the shared columns and the rows from both df1 and df2.
2. then it removes dublicate rows.
3. then it merges it with columns from df1 that are not in df2.

columns in df2 that are not in df1 are deleted.

Here is an example

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   "y": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
                   "c": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}, index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["new x", "new x", "new x"],
                   "y": [0, 0, 0]}, index=[2, 4, 6])

print(update_shared_columns(df1, df2))
```

Which produces the output

```
       x  y  c
1      1  1  1
2  new x  0  1
3      3  1  1
4  new x  0  1
5      5  2  1
6  new x  0  1
7      7  3  1
8      8  3  1
9      9  3  1
```